# best way to seperate platform specific code in Titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am wondering how would you separate platform specific code in Titanium, would you use
conditional statements such as

```
var osname = Ti.platform.osname;
if(osname == "android") {
// do something
}
else {//iOS
//do something else
}
```

or would you use require and have 2(or more) separate code such as

```
example.android.js
example.iphone.js
```

and have Titnaium require the right one, or is there another way that I am not aware of?

Thanks

Comment: Too general question without exact right answer. In most cases it's just matter of preference. Rule of thumb: for just couple of lines use conditional statement and when most of the code is different use separate files.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to use Alloy where you can modularize your code and include them in the App based on the platform and device type (handheld and tablet). 
Furthermore, you can write global available code in Alloy, so that you can hold platform independant code in the global space.

Otherwise I second Armin's comment.

Answer (score 0):

As per current scenario, I would suggest to use [Alloy MVC structure](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Alloy_Framework). If you want to go with traditional structure then you can use commonJS method.